# smarty syntax - isset

Tags: smarty, isset

```
{if isset({$LANG.domainmoreinfo}){$LANG.domainmoreinfo}{/if}
```

This seems to be an incorrect syntax, can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Can't we apply a isset on "$LANG.domainmoreinfo" (thing :s) perhaps?
*(yes, I'm that newbie)*

**Update**:
This is a string (so I believe), if that's the case, then, I can't use isset and I should use something that verifies is length?

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i think you don't need to use {} for variable in a condition,

```
{if isset($LANG.domainmoreinfo)}
   {$LANG.domainmoreinfo}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
{if isset($LANG.domainmoreinfo)} {$LANG.domainmoreinfo} {/if}
```

I think there was an issue with your curly braces, not necessary within the `isset()` condition as @kinnou02 said because the statement is already being processed by smarty due to the curly brace right at the start of the `if`

Comment: Your syntaxes are equal, I voted the first one. Thanks for that {} comment. I will mark as usefull.